# Error al mostrar datos en un bucle con un switch

Tags: c#

Necesito con un método cargar una matriz, que tenga la misma cantidad (filas) de apostantes que se pide al principio y 5 columnas que son 5 bolillas de la lotería. Por ahora tengo esto:

```
class Program
{
    static void nuevo(int[] lista, int cantidad, ref int tope)

        lista[tope] = cantidad;
        tope++;
    }


    static void jugada (int[,]m, int napostante)
        {



            for(int col=0; col<m.GetLength(1);col++)
            {
                Console.Write(Jugada : ");
                m[napostante,col] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

               }
              }





    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string[] nombre;
        string[] apellido;
        int opcion, tope = 0, cantidad;
        bool seguir = true;





        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese la cantidad de apostantes: ");
        cantidad= Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        int[] vector = new int[cantidad];
        nombre = new string[cantidad];
        apellido = new string[cantidad];
        int[,] matriz = new int[cantidad, 5];


        while (seguir)
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("\t\t1-Agregar apuesta");

            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.Write("Ingrese opcion: ");
            opcion = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            switch (opcion)
            {

                case 1:
                    Console.Clear();
                    Console.WriteLine("\t\t1 - Agregue una apuesta: ");
                    if (tope < nombre.Length)
                    {

                        Console.Write("Ingrese Nombre: ");
                        nombre[tope] = Console.ReadLine();
                        Console.Write("Ingrese Apellido: ");
                        apellido[tope] = Console.ReadLine();
                        cargarjugada(matriz, tope - 1);
                        agregar(vector, cantidad, ref tope);





                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("No hay mas cupos");
                        Console.ReadLine();
                    }



                    break;
```

Pero el tema es que al ejecutar el programa me pregunta cuántos apostantes son, le pongo 2, cuando voy a generar la apuesta me pregunta nombre apellido y se quiebra el ingresar el primer numero. Necesito que registre a cada napostante con su jugada ya que luego tengo que desplegar las jugadas de cada apostante, ver si alguien gano, etc.

¿Me faltará algún `while` en el `switch` del case 1? ¿Cómo puedo solucionar este problema?

Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que defines `matriz` como `int[,] matriz = new int[cantidad, 5];`. Es decir, cuando elijes 2 apostantes, tienes un `int[2,5]`.

Luego, en el método `cargarjugada` tienes dos bucles `for`, uno para cada dimension de `matriz`. Con lo que,cuando llamas al método con `matriz` siendo `[2,5]`, logicamente el bucle se repite 2 * 5 = 10 veces. Lo que debes hacer es modificar el método para que reciba para que jugador hay que obtener los numeros, algo asi:

```
static void cargarjugada (int[,]m,int jugador)
{   
     for(int col=0; col<m.GetLength(1);col++)
     {
          Console.Write("Ingrese su Jugada : ");
          m[jugador,col] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
     }

}
```

Y modificar la llamada con algo asi:

```
cargarjugada(matriz,tope);
```

Comment: A ver,estas llamando a `cargarjugada` con cada jugador que introduces,asi que debes rellenar la fila correspondiente a ese jugador,no recorrer todas las filas cada vez. Por eso solo hay un for en el método. Simplemente prueba el codigo que te he puesto y mira a ver si funciona. Tambien te recomiendo que depures tu aplicación paso a paso,y asi seguiras el flujo del programa y entenderas porque falla

Comment: Gracias, es que soy novato y tengo muchas dudas, lo he copiado asi como esta, pide nombre, apellido, y cuando pide jugada al colocar el 1er numero se quiebra y me marca el error aqui:  m[napostante,col] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); indice fuera de los limites de la matriz, me tiene que pedir 5 numeros, al colocar el primero se quiebra asi, gracias

Comment: Veo que cambiaste el nombre a `napostante`. Haz una cosa,edita tu pregunta y copia como está ahora tu codigo

Comment: Si, lo cambie para tener una mejor referencia en lo personal, gracias estimado

Comment: Vale,era un fallo mio. Al metodo debes pasarle `tope` como `napostante`,no tope-1. Modifica esa linea por `cargarjugada(matriz,tope);` Ya edite la respuesta para reflejarlo

Comment: Pikoh mas que agradecido con tu ayuda!!!! Mil gracias! Luego tengo que listar, eliminar y generar un randomico de 5 (por l oque veo es igual pero con random), cualquier cosa pedire tu ayuda, ahora muchas gracias!

Comment: Tienes idea como puedo controlar que los numeros ingresados esten entre 0 y 48 y que si colocan letras aparezca un mensaje, se que se hace con un try y catch  y un if para los numeros, pero donde lo coloco? en el metodo o en el case antes de invocar al metodo?

Comment: Creo que deberías hacer una nueva pregunta, repreguntar algo diferente va en principio en contra de la esencia del sitio. De todas maneras, para comprobar si es un numero lo que se ingresa mira el método `isNaN`

Comment: como puedo hacer para controlar que los números ingresados no se repitan?

Comment: Como ya te dije, realiza una nueva pregunta, poniendo lo que has intentado y trataremos de ayudarte :)